# before_filter not inheriting from parent controller correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry if this may be a stupid question but I'm unable get my filters to inherit the way the Rails 3 documentation is saying it should.

Specifically I have an Admin controller that was generated via:

```
rails generate controller admin
```

I added only a single action to the admin controller, the before filter & the private filter method

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  before_filter require_admin_creds

  def index
  end

private

  def require_admin_creds
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
        flash[:error] = ...
        redirect_to ....
    end
  end
end
```

I next then created my nested resources under the admin section with:

```
rails generate scaffold admin/model
```

While my admin index is indeed getting the filter, the admin/model index (or any other actions) are not.  What is happening under the hood here that I must have excluded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the before_filter will only apply to the specific controller where is defined.  Where do you see that it should be inherited?  Also, generating admin/model is creating a controller in the admin namespace... this isn't inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

Make require_admin_creds a protected method, not private.

Comment: Can't comment on others posts yet, so to Sean Hills comment: Yes the before_filters are inherited.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  He still needs to change the Admin::ModelController to inherit from the AdminController because simply placing the ModelController into the Admin namespace does not create the inheritance.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change:

```
Admin::ModelController < ApplicationController
```

to

```
Admin::ModelController < AdminController
```

?

This creates the inheritance, not placing the model controller into the admin namespace.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right on both parts.  I appreciate the newbie help.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your syntax. You have:

```
before_filter require_admin_creds
```

but I think that should be:

```
before_filter :require_admin_creds
```

where you use a symbol, rather than a variable/method name.